# Semigroups and measure

Tags: real-analysis, semialgebras

A semialgebra $\mathcal S$ is a Set of subsets such that:

1. $\emptyset, X \in\mathcal S$ where $X$ is the Universe.
2. If $A,B \in\mathcal S$, then $A \cap B \in\mathcal S$
3. If $A \in\mathcal S$, then $A^c = A_1 \cup A_2 \cup ...... \cup A_n$ where $A_i \in\mathcal S,     
            \forall i$ and $A_j \cap A_m = \emptyset$, $\forall m \neq j$

Then:

Let $\mathcal S$ be a semialgebra and let $\mu_s : \mathcal S \to \mathbb R$ a measure of semialgebras. Suppose that exists $S_n \in\mathcal S$ such that $X = \bigcup_{i=0}^n S_n$ and $\mu_s (S_n) < \infty $. Prove that there is one only measure of $\sigma$-algebra

$\mu :\sigma(\mathcal S)$ $\to \mathbb R$ such that $\mu (S) = \mu_s(S)$ $\forall S \in\mathcal S$.

Here $\sigma(\mathcal S)$ denotes the $\sigma$-algebra generated by semialgebra $\mathcal S$.

I have no clue about how to prove this.

There's a suggestion: Use that in the case that $\mu_s(X) < \infty$, the result is valid.

Comment: You are actually talking about [semialgebras](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Measure_Theory/Basic_Structures_And_Definitions/Semialgebras,_Algebras_and_%CF%83-algebras#Semialgebras), not [semigroups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semigroup).

Comment: What is $\sum (S)$ in this context?

Comment: Well, the teacher defined semigroups that way. $\sum (S)$ is the sigma-algebra generated by the semigroup S.